# Tkinter command button not executed when clicked & no error message - (not the () or indentation issue) -

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, command

`crapsgui.py`  - being part of the scripts for a two-Dice rolling game

This is a dice game, only attached here the scripts for the GUI parts due to space limitation!

The button "New Game" does not execute the function "newGame", debugger just stops at the line of

```
def newGame(self)
```

The three lines relevant here are :

The button set up line:-

```
self.newButton = self.addButton(row=4, column=1, text="New Game", command=self.newGame)
```

The function declared line -

```
def newGame(self):
```

The looping instruction to keep button on call -

```
CrapsGUI().mainloop()
```

Before I add the part for asking user to enter "the no. of game", the function newGame(self) is working well, but them after adding more lines in the EasyFrame, the button become non- responsive! I am new to python and spent many days trying to fix it to no veins! Would be most

```
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from craps2 import Player

class Var:
def __init__(self, wins=0, losses=0, winRolls=0, lossRolls=0, number=0, Res="" ):
    self.wins = wins
    self.losses = losses
    self.winRolls = winRolls
    self.lossRolls = lossRolls
    self.number = number
    self.Res = Res   
    # these variable for control when to stop the game & calculating the roll results statistics after all games completed
```

p1=Var()

```
class CrapsGUI(EasyFrame): #set up GUI frame with two buttons
    def __init__(self):
        EasyFrame.__init__(self, title="Craps Game")
        self.newGame = None
        self.setSize(200, 200)
        self.player = Player()
        self.v1 = 1
        self.v2 = 2
        self.dieLabel1 = self.addLabel("", row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW") # Dice image 1
        self.dieLabel2 = self.addLabel("", row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW")  # Dice image 2

        self.StartArea1= self.addTextArea("Enter the number of games:  ", row=1, column=0, width=7, 
        height=1)  #Ask user to input the number of game to play
        self.inputField = self.addIntegerField(value=0, row=1, column=1)
        self.addButton(text="Enter", row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, command=self.enter)

        self.stateArea = self.addTextArea("", row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, width=10, height=5)

        self.rollButton = self.addButton(row=4, column=0, text="Roll", command=self.nextRoll)
        self.newButton = self.addButton(row=4, column=1, text="New Game", command=self.newGame)

        self.resultArea = self.addTextArea("", row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, width=17, height=7)

        self.refreshImages()

    def enter(self):    #this button to submit the inputted number of dice game to play, "number"
        p1.number = self.inputField.getNumber()
        self.outputField.setNumber(p1.number)

    def nextRoll(self):   # function to roll the dices once and display the rolling result
        self.stateArea = self.addTextArea("", row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, width=10, height=5)
        (self.v1, self.v2) = self.player.rollDice()
        total = self.v1+self.v2
        p1.Res = p1.Res + "Total = "+ str(total) + " - roll no.:"+ str(self.player.rollsCount)+ "\n"
        self.stateArea.appendText(str(Res))
        self.refreshImages()
        if self.player.isWinner():
            p1.wins += 1
            p1.winRolls += self.player.rollsCount
            self.stateArea.appendText("You won!" + " " + str(p1.wins) + ",  " + str(p1.wins + p1.losses)+ ",  
            "+str(p1.number))
            self.rollButton["state"] = "disabled"
        elif self.player.isLoser():
            p1.losses += 1
            p1.lossRolls += self.player.rollsCount
            self.stateArea.appendText("You lose!"+ " " + str(p1.losses) + ",  " + str(p1.wins + p1.losses) + 
            ",  "+str(p1.number))
            self.rollButton["state"] = "disabled"

        if (p1.wins + p1.losses) == number:  #when number of wins plus losses = number, disable Roll button
            self.resultArea.appendText("The total number of wins is " +str(p1.wins) +"\n")
            self.resultArea.appendText("The total number of losses is " +str(p1.losses) +"\n" )
            if wins > 0:
            self.resultArea.appendText("The average number of rolls per win is " +str(p1.winRolls/p1.wins) 
            +"\n")
            if p1.losses > 0:
                self.resultArea.appendText("The average number of rolls per loss is " 
                +str(p1.lossRolls/p1.losses) +"\n")
                self.resultArea.appendText("The winning percentage is " +str(p1.wins/p1.number) )
            else:
                pass

    def newGame(self):  #button to start another game
        Res=""
        if (p1.wins + p1.losses) < number:
            self.player = Player()
            self.v1 = 1
            self.v2 = 1
            self.stateArea.setText("")
            self.refreshImages()
            self.rollButton["state"] = "normal"
        else:
            self.rollButton["state"] = "disabled"

    def refreshImages(self):   #refresh the images of two dices in use
        fileName1 = "DICE/"+str(self.v1)+".gif"
        fileName2 = "DICE/"+str(self.v2)+".gif"
        self.image1 = PhotoImage(file=fileName1)
        self.dieLabel1["image"] = self.image1
        self.image2 = PhotoImage(file=fileName2)
        self.dieLabel2["image"] = self.image2

def main():
    CrapsGUI().mainloop()   #loop to make the two command button on call 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: all variables created outside functions and methods are global - you don't need `global Res` at start. You need `global Res` only inside functions and methods.

Comment: I have amended the scripts, so that no more global variables issue! But, still the same, it stops running when the button "New Game" is clicked! Totally the same as before, no response on clicking that button!

Comment: it was only comment to your code - not solution. Comment doesn't have to resolve problem - it can comment/explain any other element in code.

Comment: problem is `self.newGame = None` which replaces `def newGame(self)` and you assign `command=None` in this button

Answer (score 0):

Problem is

```
self.newGame = None
```

which replaces

```
def newGame(self)
```

and finally you assign `command=None` when you create `self.newButton`.

You have to remove `self.newGame = None` or use different name for this variable.

Comment: I removed the "self.newGame = None" , and it works now! Thanks for your advice! Splendid !